# Can anyone tell me what these LEGO sets are?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Can someone help me identify these part built LEGO sets?  They may be Star Wars or Ninjago .

Answer (score 4):

At least some of these parts are from [4433 Dirt Bike Transporter](https://brickset.com/sets/4433-1/Dirt-Bike-Transporter).

[image]

The clue is the sticker on the assembly in the top right corner of the image. Number plate stickers typically indicate the initials of the designer (for modern sets) and then the number of the set. In this case, "DM 4433", which matches the set number 4433.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of the pieces in the picture are from set/item# 9780756663117 - "Brickmaster Star Wars".

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?B=9780756663117#T=S&O=

[image]
[image]
[image]

There appears to be some customized bits, but they are still recognizable.  Then there's that one little bit from set# 4433 that Kramii pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the [4x4 quarter circle plate in dark bluish grey](http://rebrickable.com/parts/30565/plate-round-corner-4-x-4/) and the [1x1 yellow tile](http://rebrickable.com/parts/3070b/tile-1-x-1-with-groove/14/?sets_page_size=200&sort_sets_by=0&sort_sets_dir=A#sets) only appear together in one set, the doc ock set from 2004, and that set doesn't have binoculars in it, so you're probably looking at a mix of sets here.